# Implement Branch deeplink with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, branch.io

I am trying to use branch deeplink with react.

How do I implement **branch** deeplink with react. Is it possible, if yes, any help with that

Answer (score 0):

You can check out our official React Native Integration guide here -
https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/react-native

Here's a sample TestBed project that you can checkout - https://github.com/hana-branch/testbed_simple